# jQuery: hide() box when clicking on body but not() on element itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<a href="#" id="btn">Show Box</a>` somwhere in my DOM. Additionally I have a `div#overlay` that is by default set to `display:none;`.

```
// Toggle Overlay
$('#btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#overlay').toggle();
})

$('body').not('#btn, #overlay').click(function() {
    if ( $('#overlay').is(':visible') ) $('#overlay').hide();
});
```

Why is this not working? I want the `#btn` to toggle() the overlay when clicking it. However when the overlay is visible and I click anywhere on the document (except the `#btn` itself or the `#overlay`) I want the overlay also to be hidden.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are capturing a `click` on the `body` which itself is *never* `#btn` or `#overlay`, and so it does not work as expected. What you need to check against instead is `event.target`

i.e.

```
$('body').click(function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    if(!target.is('#btn') && !target.is('#overlay')) {
       if ( $('#overlay').is(':visible') ) $('#overlay').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Only problem I have is that the overlay has children and when clicking on those the overlay closes because it also triggers the body click as it seems. or there is some other problem.

Comment: Any ideas why that could happen?

Answer (score 4):

Use `event.target.id` for comparing clicked area's `id`

```
$('body').click(function(e) {
   if(e.target.id != 'btn' && e.target.id != 'overlay')
      if ( $('#overlay').is(':visible') ) $('#overlay').hide();
})
```